# Regex for number surrounded by slashes

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

Like the title says, I have a (faulty) Regex in JavaScript, that should check for a "2" character (in this case) surrounded by slashes. So if the URL was http://localhost/page/2/ the Regex would pass.

In my case I have something like http://localhost/?page=2 and the Regex still passes.

I'm not sure why. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/
```

(I'm going to tell you, I didn't write this code and I have no idea how it works, cause I'm really bad with Regex)

Comment: Your regexp should look like `/\d+/`

Comment: It's looking for a `2` surrounded by `\b`'s which are word boundaries. So as long as the `2` character is considered a "word" it will match. The `(.*?)` just grab the surrounding text (greedily), presumably so you can rebuild the URL.

Comment: try losing the question marks.. ^(.*) should be sufficient if you want to match any starting sequence..

Comment: Accidentally voted for bdares's comment, which is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't check for a digit surrounded by slashes. The slashes you see are only your regex delimiters. You check for a 2 with a word boundary `\b` on each side. This is true for `/2/` but also for `=2`

If you want to allow only a 2 surrounded by slashes try this

```
/^(.*?)\/2\/(.*?)$/
```

`^` means match from the start of the string

`$` match till the end of the string

`(.*?)` those parts are matching everything before and after your `2` and those parts are stored in capturing groups.

If you don't need those parts, then Richard D is right and the regex `/\/2\//` is fine for you.

Comment: this did the trick also. accepted answer because you explained the thing with `\b`. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Seems too simple but shouldn't this work?:

```
/\/2\//
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QHac8/1/

As it's javascript you have to escape the forward slashes as they are the delimiters for a regex string.

or if you want to match any number:

```
/\/\d+\//
```

Comment: I'd imagine more likely `/\/\d+\//`